# How to get an accurate audio time-base

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I'm interested in using an audio file as a record of events taking place in time.  That is I will have multiple data streams that need to be aligned in time and I would like to use the audio file as a reference.  So, I'm wondering if it is possible to get the actual time-base for an audio stream, as referenced relative to a real-time-clock?
I appreciate that one can determine the duration of an audio clip from the sample count and the sampling frequency (say, 16KHz).  For short clips, this is probably a good estimate, but for long (multi-hour recordings) how accurate will this estimate be?  I would like to maintain sub-second accuracy over multiple hours.

Put another way, does the audio file store the actual start and stop time of the audio recording, as referenced to the RTC (real-time-clock).  This would allow one to generate a time-base for every sample in the audio file.  If so, can I get this data from a python audio library?

I'm using MP4/AAC for encoding on an Android platform and `pydub` for post-processing.

Thanks.

Comment: I don’t think audio recordings have sub-second time accuracy. [lots of people](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=audio+recording+drift&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) have discovered “drift” in their audio recordings and have devised various strategies for getting multiple (independent) recordings of the same event to align correctly. Podcasters in particular, where each host records themself locally and then combine the recordings afterward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came up with an answer that may seem like a kludge, but honestly is working pretty well for us.  It seems that that audio format specification does not allow for storing time code for the start and end of the session.  So, instead, we encoded the beginning time stamp, with millisecond resolution, the moment the record button was pressed, as a string in the filename ("2017-02-13_10-04-27-943") and recorded the audio session.  Then when recording stopped, we grabbed another time stamp, calculated the time difference in milliseconds, and then appended the duration as a string in the filename, just after closing the file ("Dur123456").  Thus, the time start and duration are referenced to the RTC (Real Time Clock) on the Android phone.  We are then able to remap the WAV/PCM timebase to the true duration.  As it turns out, "16KHz" is not actually 16,000Hz.  We are finding errors on the order of a seconds for 10 minutes of audio recording.  It may not seem like much,  but for multi-hour recordings it adds up.  Thanks.